# drupal how to apply a theme without setting it to default

Tags: drupal-7

I am building a new theme. is it possible to conduct like the final testing and tuning of the theme on the site without showing it the the users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Theme Key](https://drupal.org/project/themekey) module has a functionality to do that. Here, you can enable several themes on the same site, which will change depending on the url, content type, etc.

> ThemeKey allows you to define simple or sophisticated theme-switching rules which allow automatic selection of a theme depending on current path, taxonomy terms, language, node-type, and many, many other properties.

So, you don't necessarily have to set your theme as default and just apply it to any particular section of your site to check it out. Hope that helps.